# How to create and activate virtual environment in windows 10 using bash command

Tags: windows, python-3.5, git-bash

I am trying to activate my virtual environment using bash command in windows 10. I am using python 3.5.1 . **F:\Python\Python35** is the location where my `python.exe` is located. My virtual environment's name is `myvenv` and **F:\Python\virtualenvironment\myvenv** is the location where my virtual environment is located. I created my virtual environment using following bash command

```
Nazem Mahmud@DESKTOP-VQR06GL MINGW64 /f/Python/virtualenvironment 
$ python -m venv myvenv
```

But i can't activate it now. I used

```
Nazem Mahmud@DESKTOP-VQR06GL MINGW64 /f/Python/virtualenvironment
$ source myvenv/Scripts/activate
```

and

```
Nazem Mahmud@DESKTOP-VQR06GL MINGW64 /f/Python/virtualenvironment/myvenv 
$ source Scripts/activate
```

But nothing works. It gives me error like
`bash: Scripts/activate: No such file or directory`

Can anyone say how can i activate my virtual environment using bash command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have solved it.

At first, I install `virtualenv` using following command:

```
Nazem Mahmud@DESKTOP-VQR06GL MINGW64 /f/Python/virtualenvironment
$ pip install virtualenv
```

Then I create a new virtual environment using this command:

```
Nazem Mahmud@DESKTOP-VQR06GL MINGW64 /f/Python/virtualenvironment
$ py -m virtualenv env
```

Here, `env` is my virtual environment name. Next, to activate this virtual environment I ran following command:

```
Nazem Mahmud@DESKTOP-VQR06GL MINGW64 /f/Python/virtualenvironment
$ source env/Scripts/activate
```

Comment: I get the error "no module virtualenv" even after installing it

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem but it was because I was in the same directory as my virtual environment. Try navigating back to the root directory (use `cd-`) of the project and activate your virtual environment.